# work with sass in rails 4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this following errors `File to import not found or unreadable: compass.`
I'm folowwing the tuts on railscast I have this in my Gemfile

```
group :assets do
  gem "compass", "~> 0.12.2"
end
```

and I have remove everything in my /assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss to put this

```
@import "compass";
@import "compass/reset";
@import "susy"; //susy-framework
//whithin /assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "base";
@import "layout";
@import "modules";
```

on my apllication.html.erb I have this  `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>`

Answer (score 0):

From your rails root directory, try running

compass compile

If that doesn't work, try moving it outside of your :assets group. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi D-R.! from rails root I had this. `Nothing to compile. If you're trying to start a new project, you have left off the directory argument.`

Comment: Having it inside of 'group :assets' can apparently cause this; edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I still have the same output when I  remove group :asset. Also I did update my Gemfile for this gem 'sass-rails' and gem 'compass-rails' some .scss file are working but others gives me error like ``clearfix': Undefined mixin` or `Invalid CSS after "headings": expected selector, was "()"` that was for the SASS headings() function . Do you think is due by not compiling it?

Comment: Now when I do an `rake assets:precompile` I have this error `Undefined mixin 'text-shadow'.`

Comment: 'Undefined mixin' sounds like an import problem; are you sure it's being imported in your modules? What does your call to headings() look like? Did you provide a range for it?

Comment: headings() is on my partials _base and it's a builtin sass helpers [link]http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/selectors/

Comment: I re-did a small app following the compas guide [link]https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails but I still have the same error.